# How can one set a CSS property with the !important flag via the DOM?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

So, in my stylesheet, I have a property in a rule that matches `myElement` which uses the `!important` flag.

Then, in a script, I need to adjust that property of `myElement`.  The code I'm using does nothing:

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('myElement');
myElement.style.property = 'newValue';
```

This threw me for a loop, because while nothing was visibly happening on my page, the element even showed with the new property value under element.style in Chrome's element inspector.  So it took me a while to figure it out, but then it hit me that I have to also put the `!important` flag in the `newValue` setting.  **Does anyone know how to do this programmatically?**

Comment: And so begins the `!important` war... Real solution is to not use it.

Comment: this question is a great description of why using `!important` anywhere in your code is generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here you go:

```
myElement.style.setProperty( 'property', 'newValue', 'important' );
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/mJHEf/

Comment: +1. Should also be noted, though, for IE it needs to be IE9 or up for the `setProperty()` method to work as intended.